# What does li $v0,10 , in Mips?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am just starting with Mips so this may sound simple but:
When I wrote the code above **without** li $v0,10 instruction , I got an error message: memory adress out of bound
When  , I added it , it worked with no warnings.
What does this means?

```
.text
.globl main
main:
 li $t1,27
li $t2,2
mulou $t3,$t1,$t2
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Answer (score 6):

`li` itself just loads an immediate into a register. In this particular case, the service routine on the other side of `syscall`  looks at the value in `$v0` to tell what function is requested. `10` is the code for `exit` (see [list of system calls supported by spim](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html)). If you don't set `$v0` then some random function will be performed based on what value `$v0` happens to contain. Likely it isn't going to be `exit` so the cpu tries to continue executing whatever is after your code in memory which will sooner or later crash.

Comment: so in HLL terms , 10 stands for "exit" ?

Comment: Yes. You can imagine the OS service routine having something like a `switch ($v0) { case 10: do_exit(); }`

Comment: I read that registers v0, v1 store results. Is there any chance that v0 is used for something other than to exit the program ? And how come , not all assembly programs end with this instruction (I saw online some code without it).

Comment: You can use `$v0` for whatever you want. It's a general purpose register. Depending on the environment there may be other ways to exit, e.g. `jal exit` or even just returning `jr $ra`.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, it's not the `li` doing the exit. The `syscall` invokes the operating system, which then looks at `$v0`. You can load `10` into `$v0` and nothing special will happen unless you then proceed to do a `syscall` (so thy process, who, being naughty in my sight, shall snuff it).